# CMake links against wrong version of library

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I have some CMake packages that depend on Protobuf v2.5, and one that depend on Protobuf v3.4. I have v2.5 installed system-wide in `/usr`, whereas v3.4 is only used in a single package. Therefore, I put the headers for v3.4 in a `3rdparty` subdirectory inside the package where it is being used, and then I call `include_directories(3rdparty)` in my CMakeLists.txt so it can be found.

As for the shared libraries, the .so files for v2.5 are present in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, and I installed the .so files for v3.4 to `/usr/lib`. In short, this is what the directory structure looks like:

**v2.5:**
headers: `/usr/include`
libraries: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

**v3.4:**
headers: `<MY_PACKAGE_SRC_DIRECTORY>/3rdparty`
libraries: `/usr/lib`

Now, the problem arises when I try to link against v3.4. To simplify things, I don't use any CMake module files to find protobuf v3.4, rather I just add a hard-coded path `/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so` to the list of libraries to link against when creating a target. But even so, when I run `ldd my_target_executable`, the result is:

`libprotobuf.so.8 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.8`

meaning that it is linking against the libraries for v2.5 in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, even though I added a hard-coded path to the correct .so file in `/usr/lib` in the call to `target_link_libraries` when building this executable.

What is worth noting is that if I remove the .so files in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, then it does link against the correct .so file in `/usr/lib`, so it appears that for some reason, CMake searches in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` before using the library path that I provide it. How can I change this behavior, or fix this problem in any other way?

***UPDATE***
The library file for v3.4 `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so` is a link to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.14` which in turn is a link to the actual file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.14.0.0`.

Now, if I change the hard-coded path that I give in `target_link_libraries` from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so` to either the second symlink  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.14`, or to the actual file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.14.0.0`, then my executable correctly links againt v3.4. It appears that the name of the provided symlink has some effect on CMake's behavior.

Comment: What do you have in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Are you sure that cmake is generating an incorrect linker line or is the problem with how dynamic loading works on Linux?  You can use cmake to adjust how this works using RPATH commands. I would have thought that you could specify specific version of the library to load like if you specified it as the link library with the full library name (e.g. libFoo.so.2) but I've never had to try this. https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Only a couple of entries to my CUDA installation in `/usr/local/cuda`
@Fred That might be happening, but I can't be sure. In the `link.txt` file generated by CMake, there is only a string `-lprotobuf` i.e. cmake doesn't resolve it to the absolute path.

Comment: Added an update to the original question. I think it's a helpful clue.

Comment: What is your link line, what is CMake generating and how do you detect protobuf? What the entries in CMakeCache.txt? But clearly, the issue is the `-lprotobuf`. You might want to use the good `so` directly in `add_library`.

Comment: Disregarding the long list of libraries stemming from other unrelated libraries (OpenCV, Boost, etc.) the linker command is `.....-rdynamic -lprotobuf ........ -Wl,-rpath`. BUT when I change the hard-coded library path to `libprotobut.so.14` (see update in original question for more details), then the linker line changes to  `.....-rdynamic /usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.14 ........ -Wl,-rpath`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't cmake specifically but also how things work on Linux with gcc and shared libraries.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

When you specify `target_link_libraries( target /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so)` this sets up linking as `-lprotobuf`.  In this case it should just use any version of the library it finds first.

`target_link_libraries( target /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.14)` adjusts the cmake generated link line to use a specific library version.  This seems to tell gcc to link against that version which will change what happens at run-time and library searches.

[target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html)

> There are some cases where CMake may ask the linker to search for the library (e.g. /usr/lib/libfoo.so becomes -lfoo), such as when a shared library is detected to have no SONAME field. See policy CMP0060 for discussion of another case.

Comment: I see. But doesn't this basically render the full path that I provide irrelevant? I mean, if I explicitly mention `/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so`, why does CMake still translate it to `-lprotobuf.so`in the linking line (which in turn causes Linux's default mechanism for finding dynamic libraries to kickin)? Doesn't this basically mean that a system-wide installation of any library overrides a custom library path provided by the developer (unless the version is also specified)?

Comment: It's documented that cmake does this but I don't know the reason why.

Comment: I haven't tried it but maybe linking against `/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so` may still mean to use any version of `libprotobuf.so`.   So the path you gave it doesn't matter?

Comment: No. Only when the version is also specified, as in `/usr/lib/libprotobuf.so.14`, does it use the full stated path while linking.